# Why is my sprite speeding up without changing variables?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a bug in this code somewhere that cause the ship to fly faster and faster in space after returning from the planet. I cant figure this one out.

I set the speed to 0.1 so that its super slow in space. When you click on the planet, i run a function that will move canvas's off screen and use zindex to brong a div tag to the top of the stack. When you land and return to orbit, the ship will move slightly faster. After doing it about 10-15 times the ship moves far greater than the 0.1 speed that is set. I will include the html, js and css so you can run it to test.

Here is the whole code.

```
// Canvas Context's
var canvasMS = document.getElementById('MainScreen_cvs');
var ctxMain = canvasMS.getContext('2d');
var canvasShip = document.getElementById('Ship_cvs');
var ctxShip = canvasShip.getContext('2d');
var PlanetDiv = document.getElementById('PlanetDiv');
var OrbitReturn = document.getElementById('OrbitReturn');
var canvasPlanets = document.getElementById('Planets_cvs');
var ctxPlanets = canvasPlanets.getContext('2d');
var canvasHUD = document.getElementById('HUD_cvs');
var ctxHUD = canvasHUD.getContext('2d');
var canvasSurface = document.getElementById('Surface_cvs');
var ctxSurface = canvasSurface.getContext('2d');

// ----------------------------------End Canvas Context


var Player1;
var Planet1;
var planetClicked;
var gameWidth = canvasMS.width;
var gameHeight = canvasMS.height;
var mouseX = 10000;
var mouseY = 10000;
var SpaceMapX = 10;
var SpaceMapY = 10;
var SurfaceMap = 0;
var SurfaceMap2 = -1600;
var inSpace = true;
var onSurface = false;
var requestAnimFrame =  window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                        window.oRequestAnimationFrame;


// Load Images

var imgMap = new Image();
imgMap.src = 'images/bg1.png';

var imgButtons = new Image();
imgButtons.src = 'images/button_sprite.png';

var imgBlueWindow = new Image();
imgBlueWindow.src = 'images/blue_window.png';

var imgSprite = new Image();
imgSprite.src = 'images/sprite.png';

var imgPlanets = new Image();
imgPlanets.src = 'images/earthlike_p1.png';

var imgBluesky1 = new Image();
imgBluesky1.src = 'images/bluesky1.png';

var imgBluesky2 = new Image();
imgBluesky2.src = 'images/bluesky2.png';

imgMap.addEventListener('load',init,false);
// ------------- End Loading Images


//-------------------- Create Game Objects ----------------

function CreateGameObjects(){
    Player1 = new Ship();
    Planet1 = new Planet(); 
};

//---------------END CREATING GAME OBJECTS------------------


function init(){  //----------------------------------------------- GAME INITIALIZATION 
    document.addEventListener('keydown',checkKeyDown,false);
    document.addEventListener('keyup',checkKeyUp,false);
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", checkMouseDown, false);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", checkMouseUp, false);
    CreateGameObjects();
    Loop();
};

function Loop() {    // ---------------- Main Game Loop
        clearCtx();
        DrawGameObjects();
        requestAnimFrame(Loop);
};
function planetSurface(){

        if(onSurface){
            clearCtx();
            HUD();
            Player1.draw();

            if(mouseY < 21 && mouseX > 693){
                ReturntoOrbit();
            }
            planetClicked.drawSurfaceImg();
            var CloseButton = '<button style="float:right;" type="button">Return to Orbit</button>' ;
            OrbitReturn.innerHTML = CloseButton;



            requestAnimFrame(planetSurface);
        }
};

function DrawGameObjects(){
    Player1.draw();
    Planet1.draw();
    HUD();
};

function HUD(){
    canvasHUD.style.zIndex = "100";

    if (onSurface){
        ctxHUD.fillStyle = "#000";
        ctxHUD.fillText("locSurface: " +  planetClicked.locSurface, 20,30);
    }
    if (inSpace)
        ctxHUD.fillStyle = "#fff";


    ctxHUD.fillText("Speed: " +  Player1.speed, 60,60);
    ctxHUD.fillText("drawX: " + Player1.drawX, 600,40);
    ctxHUD.fillText("drawY: " + Player1.drawY, 600,30);

  //    ctxHUD.fillText("Planet Clicked: " + Planet1.isClicked, 600,50);
}
//----------------------------------------------------------- Objects 
 /************************************************************************************/
//--------------------------------- SPACE SHIP --------------------------------------

function Ship(){

    this.srcX = 0;
    this.srcY = 0;
    this.srcW = 60;
    this.srcH = 60;
    this.drawX = 20 ;
    this.drawY = 50 ;
    this.speed = 0;
    this.surfaceSpeed = 10;
    this.drift = 0.45;
    this.w = 16;
    this.h = 16;
    this.isUpKey = false;
    this.isDownKey = false;
    this.isLeftKey = false;
    this.isRightKey = false;
    this.isSpacebar = false;
    this.direction = "n/a";
    this.isMoving = false;
    this.isClicked = false;
    this.surfX = 350;
    this.surfY = 200;
};

Ship.prototype.draw = function() {
    if(inSpace)
        ctxShip.drawImage(imgSprite,this.srcX,this.srcY,this.srcW,this.srcH,this.drawX,this.drawY,this.w,this.h);
    if(onSurface) 
        ctxShip.drawImage(imgSprite,this.srcX,this.srcY,this.srcW,this.srcH,this.surfX,this.surfY,this.w,this.h); 

    this.checkPos(planetClicked);
};

Ship.prototype.checkPos = function (PlanetX){
    if(inSpace){
                this.srcY = 0;
                this.srcW = 60;
                this.w = 16;
                this.h = 16;
                this.speed = 0.1;
    //----------------------------- Move Ship and Map based on the speed of the ship.
        if(this.isLeftKey){
            this.drawX -= this.speed;
            if(SpaceMapX >= 1){
                SpaceMapX -= this.speed;
            }
        }

        if(this.isRightKey){
            this.drawX += this.speed;
            if(SpaceMapX <= 2190)SpaceMapX += this.speed;
        }

        if(this.isDownKey){
            this.drawY += this.speed;
            if(SpaceMapY <= 2490)SpaceMapY += this.speed;

        }
        if (this.isUpKey) {
            this.drawY -= this.speed;
            if(SpaceMapY >= 1){
                SpaceMapY -= this.speed;            
            }

        }
        if (SpaceMapY < 0) {SpaceMapY = 0;}
        if (SpaceMapX < 0 ) {SpaceMapX = 0}
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------END
//-----------------------------------Change Ship Graphic based on direction and map boundaries.
                if(this.isUpKey) this.srcX = 360;
                if(this.isDownKey) this.srcX = 120;
                if(this.isLeftKey) this.srcX = 240;
                if(this.isRightKey) this.srcX = 0;
                if(this.isUpKey && this.isLeftKey) this.srcX = 300;
                if(this.isUpKey && this.isRightKey) this.srcX = 420;
                if(this.isDownKey && this.isLeftKey) this.srcX = 180;
                if(this.isDownKey && this.isRightKey) this.srcX = 60;
                if (this.drawX <= 5) this.drawX = 5;
                if (this.drawY <= 5) {this.drawY = 5};
                if (this.drawY >= 480) {this.drawY = 480};
                if (this.drawX >= 780) {this.drawX = 780};
    //----------------------------------------------------------------END
    ctxMain.drawImage(imgMap,SpaceMapX,SpaceMapY,gameWidth,gameHeight,0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight);
    }
    if (onSurface) {
                this.srcY = 240;
                this.srcW = 92;
                this.w = 93;
                this.h = 60;

        if(this.isLeftKey){
            PlanetX.locSurface -= this.surfaceSpeed;
            SurfaceMap += this.surfaceSpeed;
            SurfaceMap2 += this.surfaceSpeed;
            PlanetX.MapDirection = -1; 
            this.srcX = 93;
        }
        if(this.isRightKey){
            PlanetX.locSurface += this.surfaceSpeed;
            SurfaceMap -= this.surfaceSpeed;
            SurfaceMap2 -= this.surfaceSpeed;
            PlanetX.MapDirection = 1;
            this.srcX = 0;
        }
    }
};

//------------------------------END OF SPACE SHIP ------------------------------------


//----------------------------- PLANET OBJECT INFO ------------------------------------

function Planet(){

    this.srcX = 0;
    this.srcY = 0;
    this.srcW = 100;
    this.srcH = 100;
    this.w = 50;
    this.h = 50;
    this.coordX = 100;
    this.coordY = 100;
    this.planetType = "Small Earthlike Planet."
    this.drawX = this.coordX - SpaceMapX;
    this.drawY = this.coordY - SpaceMapY;
    this.surfaceIMG = imgBluesky1;
    this.isClicked = false;
    this.locSurface = 0;
};

Planet.prototype.draw = function(){
    this.drawX = this.coordX - SpaceMapX;
    this.drawY = this.coordY - SpaceMapY;
    ifClicked(this);
    if(this.isClicked){
        PlanetDiv.style.display = "block";
        var LandPlanetDivButton = '<button id="LandPlanetDivButton" type="button" onclick="landOnSurface();">Land On Surface</button>'; 
        var ClosePlanetDivButton = '<button id="ClosePlanetDivButton" type="button" onclick="ClosePlanetDiv();">Close  (x)</button><br/><p id="PlanetDivText">' ;
        PlanetDiv.style.zIndex = "2";
        HideCanvas();
        planetClicked = this;
        PlanetDiv.innerHTML = LandPlanetDivButton + ClosePlanetDivButton + this.planetType; + '</p>';

    }
    ctxPlanets.drawImage(imgPlanets,this.srcX,this.srcY,this.srcW,this.srcH,this.drawX,this.drawY,this.w,this.h);
};
Planet.prototype.drawSurfaceImg = function(){
    if(SurfaceMap2 >= 0) SurfaceMap2 = -1600;
    if(SurfaceMap2 < -1600) SurfaceMap2 = -1;
    if(SurfaceMap >= 1600) SurfaceMap = 0;
    if(SurfaceMap < 0) SurfaceMap = 1599;
    ctxSurface.drawImage(this.surfaceIMG, 0, 0, 1600, gameHeight, SurfaceMap, 0, 1600, gameHeight);
    ctxSurface.drawImage(this.surfaceIMG, 0, 0, 1600, gameHeight, SurfaceMap2, 0, 1600, gameHeight);
};

//----------------------------- END OF PLANET OBJECT -----------------------------------


//-----end Objects
function randomFromTo(from,to){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(to-from+1)+from);
};

function closestNum(Num, a){
    var num = Num + (gameWidth/2);
    var closest = a[0];
    var difference = Math.abs (num - closest);
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            var difference2 = Math.abs (num - a[i]);
            if (difference2 < difference) {
                difference = difference2;
                closest = a[i];
            }
        }
    return closest;
};

function sortNum(a)
{
    var swapped;
    do{
        swapped = false;
        for (var i=0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
            if (a[i] > a[i+1]) {
                var temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }while (swapped);
};

function ifClicked(obj){
    if(mouseX >= obj.drawX && mouseX <= obj.drawX + obj.w){
        if(mouseY >= obj.drawY && mouseY <= obj.drawY + obj.h){
            obj.isClicked = true;
        }
    }
    else{
        obj.isClicked = false;
    }
};


function clearCtx() {

    ctxMain.clearRect(0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight);
    ctxShip.clearRect(0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight);
    ctxPlanets.clearRect(0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight);
    ctxHUD.clearRect(0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight);
    ctxSurface.clearRect(0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight);
};

function checkKeyDown(e){
    var keyID = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(keyID === 38 || keyID === 87){ // up arrow or W key
        Player1.isUpKey = true;
        Player1.direction = "North";
        Player1.isMoving = true;
        e.preventDefault();
    }   
    if(keyID === 39|| keyID === 68){ // right arrow or D key
        Player1.isRightKey = true;
        Player1.direction = "East"
        Player1.isMoving = true;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if(keyID === 40 || keyID === 83){ // down arrow or S key
        Player1.isDownKey = true;
        Player1.direction = "South";
        Player1.isMoving = true;
        e.preventDefault();
    }   
    if(keyID === 37 || keyID === 65){ // left arrow or A key
        Player1.isLeftKey = true;
        Player1.direction = "West";
        Player1.isMoving = true;
        e.preventDefault();
    }

};

function checkKeyUp(e){
    var keyID = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(keyID === 38 || keyID === 87){ // up arrow or W key
        Player1.isUpKey = false;
        Player1.isMoving = false;
        e.preventDefault();
    }   
    if(keyID === 39|| keyID === 68){ // right arrow or D key
        Player1.isRightKey = false;
        Player1.isMoving = false;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if(keyID === 40 || keyID === 83){ // down arrow or S key
        Player1.isDownKey = false;
        Player1.isMoving = false;
        e.preventDefault();
    }   
    if(keyID === 37 || keyID === 65){ // left arrow or A key
        Player1.isLeftKey = false;
        Player1.isMoving = false;
        e.preventDefault();
    }

};


function clearMouse(){
        mouseX = 10000;
        mouseY = 10000;
};

function checkMouseDown(e) {
    var mX = (e.clientX - (canvasMS.offsetLeft - canvasMS.scrollLeft));
    var mY = (e.clientY - (canvasMS.offsetTop - canvasMS.scrollTop));
    if(mX <= gameWidth && mX >= 0) mouseX = mX;
    if(mY <= gameHeight && mY >= 0) mouseY = mY;
    //mouseIsDown = true;

};

function checkMouseUp(e){
    //mouseIsDown = false;
    clearMouse();
};

function ClosePlanetDiv (){
    PlanetDiv.style.zIndex = "-2";
    PlanetDiv.innerHTML = "";
    PlanetDiv.style.display = "none";
    ShowCanvas();
};

function HideCanvas(){
     canvasShip.style.marginTop = "-10000px";
   canvasPlanets.style.marginTop = "-10000px";

};
function ShowCanvas(){
   canvasShip.style.marginTop = "-500px";
    canvasPlanets.style.marginTop = "-500px";

};

function landOnSurface(){
    ClosePlanetDiv();
    inSpace = false;
    onSurface = true;
    Player1.srcX = 0;
    planetSurface();
    canvasSurface.style.display = "block";
    OrbitReturn.style.display = "block";

};
function ReturntoOrbit(){
    OrbitReturn.style.display = "none";
    canvasSurface.style.display = "none";
    inSpace = true;
    onSurface = false;

    Loop();
};

<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Space Explorer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="Functions.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="MainScreen_cvs" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
    <div id="PlanetDiv"></div>

    <canvas id="Surface_cvs" width="800" height="500"></canvas> 
    <canvas id="Ship_cvs" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
    <canvas id="Planets_cvs" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
    <canvas id="HUD_cvs" width="800" height="500"></canvas> 
    <div id="OrbitReturn"></div>



    <div id="log">  

        <h1 style="color:blue;">Recent updates will be logged here when made live.</h1>
        <hr />
        <h3> Wednesday August 3, 2016 </h3>
        <ul>
            <li> HTML file completed. Working on getting JS files started.</li>
            <li> JS files created. </li>
            <li>Basic ship & flight functions in place. Basic star map initialized.</li>
        </ul>
        <hr />

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


body {
background: #303030;
}

#MainScreen_cvs {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    background: #777777 ;
    margin: 30px auto 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#Surface_cvs{
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: -500px auto 0px;

}
#Ship_cvs, #Planets_cvs, #HUD_cvs {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: -500px auto 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#log {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 560px;
    left: 233px;
    background: #ffffff;
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: 3;
}
#OrbitReturn{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    z-index: 3;
    margin: -500px auto 0px;
}
#PlanetDiv {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    background-image: url("images/Sky.jpg");
    z-index: -2;
    margin: -500px auto 0px;
}
#ClosePlanetDivButton{
    float: right;

}
#LandPlanetDivButton{
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
    left: 325px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#PlanetDivText{
    text-indent: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Why is there an implementation of bubble sort here…? Why not put everything on one canvas?

Comment: Is it at all possible to isolate the problem area?

Comment: To try out your code, the sprite images are missing as well. Can you fit this into a jsfiddle somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is happening with Ship.prototype.checkPos. Each time you land on the planet, it looks like the checking pauses, then starts up when you enter orbit. But this time he checkPos is getting called faster.

I could keep staring at it but you might be able to figure it out from there. I put a console.log('checkPos') at the top of that function and watched it pause and restart.

```
Ship.prototype.checkPos = function(PlanetX) {
    console.log('checkPos');
    if (inSpace) {
    ...
```

I think it might be here

```
function ReturntoOrbit() {
    OrbitReturn.style.display = "none";
    canvasSurface.style.display = "none";
    inSpace = true;
    onSurface = false;

    //Loop(); <--- this little guy. Get rid of him.
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I definately suspected the same thing but checkPos is used before landing as well. The Loop(); function is the main loop for in space and the planetSurface(); is the loop for on the planet. If i got rid off loop, i cant go back to Orbit. I will look into trying other solutions. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok, so i got rid of the Loop(); to see what would happen and it works, but im confused what Loop is running the game. Thank you for the solution but now im just baffled. Im new to programming. Is

Comment: Loop() is still running from the first time you started it. Each time you call it again, it fires up another requestAnimationFrame so now it's running twice. Then three times, etc. if you want to cancel and restart it, you can assign it's return value to a variable and use that handler to call the cancel() method. Then you'd have to restart it. But as it stands now, you only need to start the loop and it will run until the page closes.